# Export contents of table to different EXCEL files and different worksheets

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssis, sql-server-2012

I have a flat table that contains the following:

```
Categorie  | Series | Productdetails
    A         A.001    1
    A         A.001    2
    A         A.001    3
    A         A.002    1
    A         A.002    2
    B         A.002    1    
    C         A.003    1
    C         A.006    2
    C         A.008    3
```

So we have categories that have multiple series that have multiple products.
Productdetails consists of 277 columns.... really :(

I would like to export this data to excel but I am asked to provide an excel file per categorie with worksheets per series containing all the products of that series.

In the above example that would lead to 3 excel files: A.xlsx, B.xlsx and C.xlsx.

- File `A.xlsx` would contain 2 worksheets (001 and 002).
- 001 would contain 3 records, 002 would contain 2 records.
- File `B.xlsx` would contain 1 worksheet (002).
- 002 would contain 1 records.
- File `C.xlsx` would contain 3 worksheets (003, 006 and 008).
- Each would contain 1 record.

What would be the best way to tackle this? There are about 12 categories containing  in total about 200 series containing min 1 and max 14.000 products.

Greetz Henrov

Comment: Which coding experience do you have? Where do you want to solve this (within Excel, with VBA)?

Comment: I am fairly proficient in SSIS, TSQL.  I prefer to do this in SSIS, a solution in TSQL would be more than OK. I can read  most programming languages so some programming in SSIS would be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you asked me to put my comments into an answer...

Install Excel and tell Excel to import data from external sources. An assistant will lead you to the creation of an ODC-connection. This is really easy. As one result you'll find the connection string you've to use to open a connection.

This discussion gives you [some VBA](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/613722-populate-spreadsheet-sql-database.html).

In VBA First you call a `SELECT` for `DISTINCT` sheet-names. Put them in an array.

Than you traverse through this array and use always the same `SELECT` with a `WHERE SheetName='YourSheetName'` to retrieve only the data you need for one special file.

Than you use `Set wb=Workbooks.Add()` to create a new workbook with the actual file name (first declare variables!) to get a reference.

Use `Set ws=wb.Worksheets.Add()` to create sheets according to a DISTINCT sheet name list. And then fill the sheet and save it. If you need more help, just call..

The code should be roughly something like this:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

'Open connection and fill a Recordset with the distinct filenames

'Do this in a loop for all distinct file names
Set wb = Workbooks.Add()
wb.Name = "YourNameFromDistinctList"

    'Fill another Recordset with the distinct sheet names for each workbook

    'Do this in a loop for all distinct file names for each workbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets.Add()
    ws.Name = "YourSheetName"

    'Fill Sheet with data
    'either use ws.ListObjects
    'or traverse through ws.Cells

    Set ws = Nothing

wb.SaveAs "YourNameFromDistinctList"
Set wb = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

With this query you'll get your flat table together with the file's name and the sheet's name (padded as 3-digit number).

```
SELECT tbl.Categorie + '.xlsx' AS ExcelFile
      ,REPLACE(STR(DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY tbl.Categorie ORDER BY tbl.Categorie,tbl.Series),3),' ','0') AS ExcelSheetPadded 
      ,tbl.*
FROM @tbl AS tbl
```

Queries like this give you the needed counts:

```
SELECT tbl.Categorie + '.xlsx' AS ExcelFile
      ,COUNT(*) AS CountPerSheet
FROM @tbl AS tbl
GROUP BY tbl.Categorie,tbl.Series
```

With `DISTINCT`etc. it should be easy to get all the information you need.

Do you need any further help?

Comment: Well, this part was not so hard :) I am looking for a way how to get this into excel.

Comment: @Henrov OK, it was not clear to me where you've got stuck. I would use VBA within Excel. If this was possible for you I could prepare some code for you a little later.

Comment: That would be great, however, there is no Excel installed (yet) on the machine doing the work. Just the AccessDatapack. But I will try to get excel on that machine. I have spent years building stuff in Access ('97 - 2000) so it will be fun working with VBA again! Could you already sent me some code? That would be great.

Comment: @Henrov, hi, sorry for the late reply... X-mas, family... :-)   Is this still an open issue? Just a short hint: If you install Excel and you tell Excel to import data from external sources, an assistant will lead you to the creation of an ODC-connection. This is really easy. As one result you'll find the connection string you've to use to open a connection. This discussion gives you some VBA: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/613722-populate-spreadsheet-sql-database.html

Comment: @Henrov First you call a SELECT for DISTINCT sheet-names. Put them in an array. Than you traverse through this array and use always the same SELECT with a `WHERE SheetName='YourSheetName'` to retrieve only the data you need for one special file. Than you use `Workbooks.Add()` to create a new workbook with the actual file name and use `Set wb=Workbooks.Add(...)` (first declare variables!) to get a reference. use `Set ws=wb.Worksheets.Add()` to create sheets according to a DISTINCT sheet name list. And then fill the sheet and save it. If you need more help, just call...

Comment: Family is a good thing, as is Xmas. Hope you enjoyed it! It is still very much an issue, I will be getting my hands dirty with the hints you provided. Thank you! Can you put this in an answer so that I can give you the points you deserve?

Comment: @Henrov, hi thx for accepting my answer. If you don't mind it would be very nice to consider additionally voting my answers up. Beside the fact, that this gives additional rep points (I'm kind of addicted :-)  ) those up votes are the base for tag badges. Anyway: Happy coding and merry X-mas!